# Mate Kiosk Mode - customize desktop context menu & shutdown/lock buttons

Tags: kiosk-mode, mate-desktop

my goal is to configure a minimal Mate desktop that allows only Firefox and limited file management.

Up to now, I managed to strip down most of the desktop by editing the menu files in:
/etc/xdg/menus/:

- mate-applications.menu
- mate-preferences-categories.menu

so that it looks now like this:

[image: Mate-Menu]

This strips the menu for all user, which is not optimal, but will do for this scenario.
But I would also like to remove or disable the "lock screen" and "shutdown" buttons.

I tried this by configuring an appropriate dconf-Profile.
There are settings that sound promising - but have no effect:

```
# /etc/dconf/db/remote-desktop.d/
# mate-menu
[org/mate/mate-menu/plugins/system_management]
**show-quit=false**
show-package-manager=false
**show-lock-screen=false**
**show-control-center=false**
show-logout=true
show-terminal=false
```

Note: the "**" are for emphasis only, the config does not contain them!
Other settings in the same profile have the desired effect, e.g.:

```
# mate-caja
[org/mate/caja/desktop]
computer-icon-visible=false
trash-icon-visible=false

# mate-panel
[org/mate/panel/general]
locked-down=true
```

Has anyone an idea how to disable/remove the lock & shutdown buttons?

The other pain point is he desktop context menu:

[image: Desktop Context Menu]

I haven't found a way to remove/disable this or at least the menu entry "Starter anlegen" which would allow the user to create a launcher shortcut with an arbitrary executable...

Do you have an idea how to "defuse" this menu?

I'm using Mate Version 1.24.0+1.

My dconf-profile looks like this:
[image: dconf-profile structure]

```
less /etc/dconf/profile/remote-desktop 
user-db:user 
system-db:remote-desktop
```

I compile it into the dconf db with:

```
sudo dconf update
```

I activate it for the desired users by putting:

```
export DCONF_PROFILE=remote-desktop
```

in their ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc

The dconf profile seems to work generally, because the Caja settings take hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - at least partially:

One of the problems was the name of the DCONF profile "remote-desktop" - the dash is not an allowed character here. So I renamed my db and profile from "remote-desktop" to "remotedesktop". Still no breakthrough.

Then I reinstalled mate, dropping "brisk-menu" from the installation and NOT adding a top panel menu. Instead I used dconf to add just Logout and Firefox launcher objects to the top panel. You have to edit the list of panel object-ids to make these object visible and to prevent mate from "bitching" about missing applets (like brisk menu).

Now I have the desired effect (logout and starting Firefox is accessible, but not Lock-Screen and Shutdown).

Comment: Can you please tell me how to customize the right click ment items in Mate desktop? Like I would like to remove create folder, create launcher, create document, open in terminal when i right click on desktop. As well I need to add one application in right click menu items, to execute. Is possibel please let me know the steps?